# Create new column with lowest value of several columns in data.frame

Tags: r, min

I have a data.frame like this:

```
data <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,5),B=c(4,3,6),C=c(2,2,8),D=c(3,3,4))

  A B C D 
  1 4 2 3 
  3 3 2 3 
  5 6 8 4
```

Now I want to create new variable "E", which is the lowest value of columns A,B and C. So that the data.frame now looks like this:

```
 A B C D E
 1 4 2 3 1
 3 3 2 3 2
 5 6 8 4 5
```

I can do this using a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  data$E[i] <- min(data[i,c("A","B","C")])
}
```

But I was wondering whether this could be done differently (more efficient)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few ways of doing it,
with `apply` (to apply the `min` function to each row)
or `pmin` (parallel `min`).

```
pmin( data[,1], data[,2], data[,3] )
# [1] 1 2 5
do.call( pmin, data[,1:3] )
# [1] 1 2 5
apply(data[,1:3], 1, min)
# [1] 1 2 5
```